# Can anyone identify this 40-pin SMT socket on the Silicon Labs BRD4180A board?

Tags: identification, socket

This socket appears on the [Silicon Labs BRD4180A board](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/ug385-brd4180a-user-guide.pdf) and it might be nice to reuse the module on our projects after programming it.  The socket appears to have 50-mil spacing between pins.  What is it?  There are no apparent markings on the plastic itself.

Male/female:

[image: 20-pin SMT socket]

From datasheet (probably 3d render):

[image: 20-pin SMT socket male]

Comment: *TE 1-534978-5* or similar. The magic words are *side coded*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to this lies in the documentation for the BRD4001 'Wireless Starter Kit' which your BRD4180A plugs into - available from SiLabs [here](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/schematic-files/BRD4001A-A01-pkg.zip).

There you'll find the BOM spreadsheet, which tells you that the daughterboard connectors, P200 & P201, are [Samtec Tiger Eye™ TFC-120-02-L-D-A-K-TR](https://www.samtec.com/products/tfc-120-02-l-d-a-k-tr) - these are the connectors you'll need to use on your own boards to be able to re-use the BRD4180A on them.
[image]
The mating connectors on your BRD4180A are probably [SFC-120-something...](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors-headers-receptacles-female-sockets/315?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALAAxwDMdIAuoQA4AuUIAymwE4CWAOwDmIAL5jCAJjIhsqJAFowUqkzFA).
[image]

The WSTK documentation package link is posted in a SiLabs Knowledge-Base article [here](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/proprietary/knowledge-base.entry.html/2018/07/12/the_main_demensions-jSgw).

Comment: Thanks, what page linked to the schematic package?  I looked but perhaps I overlooked it.  For anyone else who might stumble upon this, here is the radio board schematic zip: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/schematic-files/BRD4180A-A01-pkg.zip

Comment: @KJ7LNW I've edited the link into my answer